# PHPExcel. How to read German .xlsm file / formulas?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

i was wondering how to read/import a Exel file, that uses **German Syntax for formulas?**

Example (this formula is working in excel):

```
=SUMME(SUMMEWENNS(Projekte2017!$R:$R;Projekte2017!$K:$K;Daten!$C$4:$C$6;Projekte2017!$H:$H;Daten!$E$3))
```

For now I get this error:

> PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception in Cell.php line 293:
>   Demo!J12 -> Formula Error: An unexpected error occured

Comment: Could you explain the connection between PHP and Excel a little better? Do you use a php-plugin/library for excel import or something similar?

Comment: I use the PHPExcel Library

Comment: Are you saying a problem occurs when you **read** the file or are you trying to **set** the formula using PhpExcel. Setting is a whole different case and indeed there are functions to handle language specifics.

Answer (score 0):

It's a weird formula.

The "SUMME" Function is the same as the "SUM" Function in English and "SUMMEWENNS" corelates to "SUMIFS".

See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b

So there is something summed up, that was already summed aup before. A sum of a sum, usually doesn't make much sense.

Before going into detail of the formula: Couldn't you just "hardcopy" the numbers into a new sheet, so that you only have the numbers and eliminate the formulas?
(Copy all, Paste into new sheet and in the context menu, choose "Values" (or "Values and Number formatting", if you like.))

In the SUMMEWENNS Formula, you first specify the area that should be summed up. After the first semicolon, you define the area that should be checked ("criteria range") and after the second semicolon the criteria, the values in the criteria range should be checked against.

You can repeat that as long as you want, so you can add a number of criteria and according ranges.
(So you should always have an odd number of parameters in the function, which is the case here).

The names before the exclamation mark (!), are references to a Excel sheet (in the same map), then follows the area in the form "startcell:finishcell".
So if you take A3:B5, the area contains the cells A3, A4, A5, B3, B4, B5.
A:A is a reference to the whole column. If you put an "$" before a row or column reference, it means that it shouldn't be changed, if you "pull" the formula to another cell.
(E.g. If you sum up column A an you extend the sum-formula to the right (by dragging from the bottom riht corner of the cell), so that it's copied to the next cell, it sums up column B, if you didn't put $ before the As)

Comment: I know hot to read the formulas and how to "translate" them to english.

Comment: Ok, so specify your Problem please! E.g.: Is the formula you stated above contained in the "Demo"-Sheet, in the cell J12?

Comment: And if you understand the formulas, then maybe you can also explain, why there is a sum of a sum and if the "copy" solution could be an option... And saying "thanks" never hurts! Thanks! ;-)

Comment: "copy" is not a solution because I import the file from the server. And the file is changed every day. I dont want to copy&past values every day. I need a fully automated import.

Answer (score 0):

The Excel file formats, xlsm in you case, does not store inside formulas in German or any other specific language. It always uses English.

When the Excel file is open, MS Excel interpret the formulas based on your machine regional settings, German in your case.

PHPExcel handles only the file format. You should use only the English version of formulas in your application or implement any translation feature if you really need the German language.

Comment: Note that PHPExcel does provide formula "translation" options, including for German; see [the PHPExcel Docs](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#locale-settings-for-formulae) for details